# AddItem with raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to use `Raycast` to add to my inventory, the game runs! And the script works! I think the problem is the storing of an item to the inventory?
Does anybody know how to fix this? Thank you in advance. 
I don't know the proper way of adding it. :(

```
public Inventory inventory;
RaycastHit hit;
GameObject pickedUpObject;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Escape)) {
        Screen.lockCursor = false;
    }
    else {
        Screen.lockCursor = true;
    }


    Ray rayc = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay (new Vector3 (0.5f, 0.5f, 0f));;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);


    if (Physics.Raycast (rayc.origin, rayc.direction,out hit, 1.5f)) {


        if(Input.GetKeyDown("e")){


            if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag=="GameItem"){
                pickedUpObject=hit.collider.gameObject; 

                Destroy(pickedUpObject);
                inventory.AddItem(pickedUpObject.GetComponent<Item>());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

then I tried collider

```
enter code here
```

and it is working! but I want the `Raycast`! :(

"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Raycasting.Update () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Items/Script/Raycasting.cs:45)"

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: With line errors please note in your code where that line is using a comment.  One issue is that `Destroy(pickedUpObject);` is called *before* you add the item to your inventory which destroys that gameobject and all components.